# I have problems with 2 divs beside each other

Tags: html, css

I want to create a dashboard for our upcoming deliveries.

Now I'm nearly done with just one problem. On the left side I want to show the name of the deliverer and in the middle there are some quick notes for the workers. It works but the middle text is aligned in order to the text length of the deliverer name.

My CSS:

```
.taskboardesc {
    padding:5px 400px 2px;
    left: 400px;
    top: 22px;
    /*margin-bottom:10px;*/
    display:inline-block;
}
.taskboardheader {
    display:inline-block;
    /*display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center;*/
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:10px 5px 2px;
}
```

My PHP code:

```
<div class="taskboardheader">
    <?= $this->url->link($this->text->e($task['title']), 'TaskViewController', 'readonly', array('task_id' => $task['id'], 'token' => $project['token'])) ?>
    <div class="taskboardesc">
        <?= $this->text->markdown($task['description']) ?>
    </div>
    <div class='task-board-date1'>
        <?php if (! empty($task['date_due'])): ?>
            <span class="task-date
                <?php if (time() > $task['date_due']): ?>
                        task-date-overdue
                <?php elseif (date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d', $task['date_due'])): ?>
                        task-date-today
                <?php endif ?>
                ">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <?= $this->dt->datetime($task['date_due']) ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem]

So how did I get the text fixed in the middle without being interrupted of the text length from the left text.

Comment: Why don't you set that into a `table` ? It would fix your column width problem

Comment: [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might work as well, and be responsive.

Comment: Agreed, this is clearly tabular data so a `table` should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'll try that with a table but isn't there a way how I could get it to work like that?

Comment: @MaxiGui

I tried that now but also with the table it don't work.

Comment: Update your question with what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do that. With grid, flex box or table. I would always use a table for such presentations. that is what they are there for. But I think you might need a quick solution.

If you will fix it fast, then you flex. You have to add to wrap container (in your case would be taskboarddesc) the style attribute display: flex instead block-inline.

simple example for visualisation only.  I have thrown out the PHP code.

```css
.taskboardesc {  
  width: 50%;  
}

.link, .task-board-date1 {
  width: 25%;  
}

.link, .task-board-date1, .taskboardesc {
  padding: 20px;
}

.taskboardheader {
  background: green;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
}

.odd {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="taskboardheader">
  <div class="link">
    LINK
  </div>
    <div class="taskboardesc">
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
    </div>
    <div class='task-board-date1'>
        DATE
            <span class="task-date">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                DATE
            </span>        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="taskboardheader odd">
  <div class="link">
    LINK
  </div>
    <div class="taskboardesc">
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
        Description Description Description Description
    </div>
    <div class='task-board-date1'>
        DATE
            <span class="task-date">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                DATE
            </span>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But it still don't work. I tried your example but I end up now having the text in the right position but under the header. So it isn't aligned vertically anymore.

Comment: @Slim_Shady I don't know your project, but there could be several reasons for this. The best thing is to build a basic framework using the code sample. Give the classes new and better names and then try to include your PHP outputs there if it works.

Comment: Sure I will. But couldn't I give the first div (taskboardheader) a fixed size or something so it wouldnt be only the size of the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to layout your items:

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
#narrow {
  width: 200px;
  background: light-blue;
  /* Just so it's visible */
}
#wide {
  flex: 1;
  /* Grow to rest of container */
  background: lightgreen;
  /* Just so it's visible */
}
```

---

```
<div id="parent">
      <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
      <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
    </div>
```

This is basically just scraping the surface of flexbox. Flexbox can do pretty amazing things.

For older browser support, you can use CSS float and a width properties to solve it.

```
#narrow {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#wide {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

---

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**:- Up-vote it if it helps you